# AppFabric Cluster

Tags: appfabric

I am having an issue with AppFabric in a load balanced environment.  For some reason when I start the AppFabric cluster, I don’t see anything listening on the ports (22233).  Below is our config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="dataCache" type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </configSections>
    <dataCache size="Small">
        <hosts>
             <host replicationPort="22236" arbitrationPort="22235" clusterPort="22234"
            hostId="2035002654" size="4095" leadHost="true" account="ServiceAccount"
            cacheHostName="AppFabricCachingService" name="Server2"
            cachePort="22233" />
            <host replicationPort="22236" arbitrationPort="22235" clusterPort="22234"
            hostId="434992406" size="4095" leadHost="true" account="ServiceAccount"
            cacheHostName="AppFabricCachingService" name="Server1"
            cachePort="22233" />
        </hosts>
    </dataCache>
</configuration>
```

If I change the config to make ONE of the servers a leadHost, that host now listens on port 22233.  But in order to keep high availability, I need both up and running.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know about AppFabric, you must have a server configured as a leadhost. Also there has to be only 1 leadhost in the cache cluster.

Please let me know if i am wrong.

Thanks and Regards
Gagan Janjua